# Entity Framework - Prevent update of lookup table

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following database schema

[image]

I try to insert a new UserEntry record with the following code

```
UserEntry dbUserEntry;

using (dbContext db = new DBContext())
{
    // check for existing record
    dbUserEntry = db.UserEntries
                    .Where(u => u.UserEntryID == userEntry.UserEntryID)
                    .Include(u => u.EntryPlayers.Select(y => y.Player))
                    .FirstOrDefault();

    if (dbUserEntry != null)
    {
        // update
        dbUserEntry.TeamName = userEntry.TeamName;
        dbUserEntry.EntryPlayers = userEntry.EntryPlayers;
    }
    else
    {
        // insert
        db.UserEntries.Add(userEntry);
    }

    return db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is that it attempts to insert into the Players table as well which is really just a lookup table.  There is an Index on that table which means the code fails.

What I really want to do is insert just the UserEntry record with the EntryPlayer details.  I do not want to do anything to the Players table.  How do I prevent it trying to insert to the Player table?

Comment: if you don't want to insert the navigation property as well, you'll have to set it null before adding both to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to make the Player entities unchanged.  This code did the trick

```
 // insert
 foreach (var entryPlayer in userEntry.EntryPlayers)
 {
     db.Entry(entryPlayer.Player).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
 }

 db.UserEntries.Add(userEntry);
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks EntryPlayer requires a PlayerID so it attempts the insert for you.

Based on the diagram, I'm not sure what the purpose of EntryPlayer is. Could you refactor as follows?

1. Move the Captain field to UserEntry
2. Remove EntryPlayer table
3. Add the Players Naviation property directly to UserEntry as 1 to many

Comment: The Player table holds 160 players that you can choose to make up your entry.  A UserEntry will only consist of 11 (Entry)Players